# SQL order rows in a table by value in another table

Tags: mysql

I am running this query to select rows from `admin` table where `display_on_website` value is 1 in `admin_meta` table.

```
SELECT 
                a.sequence as sequence, 
                CONCAT(a.forename, ' ', a.surname) as name, 
                a.position as position 
            FROM 
                admin a, admin_meta am 
            WHERE 
                a.disabled = '' AND 
                a.sequence = am.user AND 
                am.field = 'display_on_website' AND 
                am.value = '1'
```

I have a row in `admin_meta` table for each user that is `website_order` - how can i order by this value?

Comment: `ORDER BY am.website_order` ??

Comment: Who/where is still teaching or encouraging that horrible comma-join syntax after all these decades? ("horrible" is not a criticism of you, just the syntax itself.)

Comment: that wont work because it'll be another SELECT query to get that value for each user

Comment: I dont see why you need another SELECT, you say is a column of `am`. Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join with the `admin_meta` table twice, once to get the `display_on_website` value, and again to get the `website_order` value to order by.

```
SELECT a.sequence, CONCAT(a.forename, ' ', a.surname) AS name, a.position
FROM admin AS a
JOIN admin_meta AS m1 on a.sequence = m1.user
JOIN admin_meta AS m2 ON a.sequence = m2.user
WHERE a.disabled = ''
AND am1.field = 'display_on_website' AND am1.value = '1'
AND am2.field = 'website_order'
ORDER BY CAST(am2.value AS DECIMAL)
```

Comment: There you go reading the whole question and making us look bad. ;)